# CNN for unseen pattern

Tags: conv-neural-network, anomaly-detection

Suppose I have a lot of photos of 2 eye cats and other creatures, but I will receive a 3 eye cats photos, what algorithm should I use to find this 3 eye cat in the test data set?

Answer (score 0):

In general Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) might fit your problem well.

But, again there are a lot of points that you need to consider: How many samples have you got? Is there a class imbalance i.e how many cats Vs other animals (since you said particularly about cats) etc.

More description about your problem will aid you to get a more apt response.